# Возврат покупок in-app purchase

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Каким образом можно сделать возврат покупки внутри приложения. В документации описан способ для тестирования с использованием статического запроса `android.test.refunded` и описание:

> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google
>   Play responds as though the purchase was refunded. Refunds cannot be
>   initiated through Google Play's in-app billing service. Refunds must
>   be initiated by you (the merchant). After you process a refund request
>   through your Google payments merchant account, a refund message is
>   sent to your application by Google Play. This occurs only when Google
>   Play gets notification from Google payments that a refund has been
>   made. For more information about refunds, see Handling IN_APP_NOTIFY
>   messages and In-app Billing Pricing.

Т.е.  если я правильно понимаю, пользователь из самого приложения в котором он сделал покупку, сделать ее возврат - не может!? Если так, то как происходит процесс возврата более подбробно? Можно ссылку на документацию, потому что я кроме этого абзаца больше информации в ней не нашел.

Доп.вопрос:
 Нужно ли в приложении реализовывать логику для возврата покупки?